# Error al subir PDF en base64 desde 1MB

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, framework7

Tengo un problema y es que tengo una app donde se suben PDF codificados en base64, pero cuando son de 1MB o mas, ajax me reponde con un error, y es porque el archivo es demasiado grande para almacenarlo en la tabla donde la columna se llama archivo de tipo longblob, y no he podido encontrar una solucion por lo que les pido si pueden ayudarme, el codigo de javascript es el siguiente:

```js
function guardarInformeSeguridad(){
   var titulo      = $$("#titulo").val();
   var descripcion = $$("#descripcion").val();
   var archivo     = $$("#archivo").val();
   app.confirm('¿Esta seguro de crear?', 'Seguridad', function() {

      $$.ajax({type:'POST',
         url:'https://................/grabar.php',
         data:({
            titulo:titulo,
            descripcion:descripcion,
            archivo:archivo
         }),
         success: function(data){
            if(data){
               app.addNotification({
                  message: 'Creado correctamente!',
                  button: {
                     text: 'OK',                 
                  }     
               });           
            } 
         },
         error: function(data){
            app.addNotification({
               message: 'Error al grabar!',
               button: {
                  text: 'OK',
               },
            });                         
         }

      }); 

   },); 

}
```

y el archivo php es el siguiente:

```html
<?php


 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {  
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");  
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');  
     header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');   
 } 

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {  
   
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))  
         header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");  
   
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))  
         header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");  
 }

 require('conexion.php'); 
 $titulo    = '';
 $descripcion  = '';
 $archivo    = '';
 if(isset($_POST['titulo'])) $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
 if(isset($_POST['descripcion']))$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
 if(isset($_POST['archivo'])) $archivo = $_POST['archivo'];
 $con = cnn();
 $sql = "INSERT INTO seguridad SET titulo = '".$titulo ."', ";
 $sql.= " descripcion = '".$descripcion."', ";
 $sql.= " archivo = '".$archivo."' ; ";
 if($respuesta = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
  $data = "0";
 }
 print $data;
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Espero pudieran ayudarme, el mensaje de error por consola es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probablemente debas revisar tu php.ini los valores de `upload_max_filesize` y `post_max_size`. Aunque deberías pensar si es necesario guardar el archivo en la base de datos puesto que estarías consumiendo gran cantidad de espacio en datos que no son útiles en consultar.

Comment: tengo 512MB no es ese el problema

Comment: ¿Adónde tiene 512MB? En php.ini o mediante ini_set no es una unidad válida, debería ser 512M y no 512MB...